# How Can I Redirect an Old Domain to a New One?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is my server `.htaccess` content. I've a website there powered by Wordpress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Convert old permalink structure to the new one
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(\d+)$ http://example.com/?p=$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ http://example.com/$4

# Redirect all requests to .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My question is about the two lines used for redirecting requests to `.com` which act in this way:

**http://example.org/post_name/  ==>  http://example.compost_name**

As you can see an **/** is missing in the new URL between tld and the URI. I also checked with this rule too which didn't affect the result:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{HTTP_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Please help me to write an appropriate redirect rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine to me, and shouldn't redirect in that way. I think you just have the broken redirect cached in your browser. Try clearing your cache and testing again. You could set the redirects to 302 instead of 301 while you're testing, which is a temporary redirect and probably not cached.

**Update**

On further investigation by the OP, it turns out there was a server redirection which conflicted with the `.htaccess` rewrite rule and was preventing it from working properly. Removing those redirections solved the problem.

Comment: It'll be useful but doesn'n solve my issue, because I'm sure about that's not a cache. I had test it from different browsers and with different post_names.

Comment: Well it can't be coming from that `.htaccess` that you posted. None of those could be redirecting to example.com without the forward slash, as every one has the forward slash explicitly added to the redirect. Perhaps it's cached on a reverse cache you have in front of your web server? Such as Varnish? Or you have some other redirect rules in place elsewhere.

Comment: I think you are right. because I changed my rule to example2.com but it doesn't take affect. how can I clear this type of cache?

Comment: It depends on what cache it is. Have a look at the full HTTP headers coming with the redirect, using something like "Live HTTP Headers" for Firefox or "httpie", and those may tell you what cache it is. Then you need to work out how to access it and how to disable it or refresh it. It very much depends on your server setup and what cache is in place.

Comment: Have you tried using a post that you have not tested before at all? Or invent one and try that. If that still redirects then it's not a cache and is some rules elsewhere.

Comment: Finally I found the bug. there was a server redirection which has conflict with my .htaccess rewrite rule and was preventing it from working properly. Removing those redirections solved this problem. Would you update your answer, please? I want to check this as the best but I want it to be a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, I updated the answer. Glad you got it fixed :)